# Enhanced for loop Java to run until specific index?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am learning how to use enhanced for loops. 
Imagine an array of size 1000, called arr. 
Writing

`for(T x: arr) { /* blah blah */ }`

will traverse the entire array. I know that I can break the loop using `break;` inside the loop body.

> Is there a way to stop the loop execution at a particular index value?

Is it possible to write this?

```
for (T x: arr[500]) {/* blah blah */}
```

So that I can avoid using a counter?

Comment: What's stopping you from using a `subArray`?. You could simply define `subArray` as `IntStream.range(0, 500)
                        .map(i -> src[i])
                        .toArray();`

Comment: If you want the index you need to use "regular" for loop `for(int i = 0;...}`

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arr).limit(500).forEach(x -> /* blah blah */);`

Answer (score 2):

In short: no.  To do that you should use the "ordinary" `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someCondition; i++) {
  if (i < someNumber) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following, but it's preferable to use conditional loop in this case.

```
for(T x: Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 500)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on java 8+, you could in fact do the same by using a subarray of the original source array

```
int[] subarray = IntStream.range(0, 500)
                        .map(i -> src[i])
                        .toArray();
//then do 
for (T x: subarray) {/* blah blah */}
```

Or you could use lambda streams to achieve the same:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).limit(500).foreach(x -> {/* blah blah */});
```

Comment: The first snippet also requires Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your enhanced loop to stop at a particular index value, you should keep track of the index by yourself. You can do something like below:

```
    int index = 0;
    for(T x: arr) {
        if(index==10) {
            break();   
        }

        //do whatever you want to do here before index value becomes 10.        
        index++;

    }
```

You can take so may other approaches, but this is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead of your code

```
for(var i=0;i<500;i++){
T x=arr[i];
 //your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're looking for the syntactical way to do this, and not the workaround to achieve that effect.
If I'm correct, then - No, there is no way to indicate the breaking index in the enhanced for loop, and that's one of the ideas why enhanced for loops exist - to just tell to compiler to iterate over all objects in an consecutive manner. With what you're asking for, you're effectively defeating one of the purposes of enhanced for loop, if you'll want to break it on specific index.

The reason of this is, that enhanced for loops internally take the iterator object and iterate over collection until iterator has next element.